# How to use multiple threads in Julia 1.0?

Tags: multithreading, julia

I have a script that uses the **@threads** macro. When I execute the script in terminal like

```
$ julia -p 4 my_script.jl
```

Where the file contains:

```
println("This program is using ", Threads.nthreads(), " threads")
```

prints than I'm using only one thread. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 6):

The switch `-p 4` starts Julia with 4 processes not threads.

To start Julia with 4 threads use command:

```
$ export JULIA_NUM_THREADS=4
```

in Bash (under Windows use `set JULIA_NUM_THREADS=4` in Command Prompt or `$env:JULIA_NUM_THREADS=4` in Powershell).

Then you can start Julia just like:

```
$ julia
```

and it will see 4 threads.